# Ajax request to admin-ajax.php and window.location.href

Tags: ajax

In relation to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111751/ajax-template-how-to-handle-head-section) question, I don't understand the meaning of:

> Instead of sending the ajax request to the admin-ajax.php, send it
>   to the same url (using js window.location.href ) but including
>   an endpoind that can be 'mobile' or 'desktop'. An hook into
>   template_include filter will do the rest. Hope it's clear

This is my call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        data: ({action : 'get_mobile_template'}),
        success: function(data) {
        document.write(data);
        }
    });
```

Is there anybody who understands this matter and is able to come up with an example?

Comment: To me you MUST use admin-ajax.php for your AJAX requests in WordPress

Comment: but then, how do you conditionally load stuff into the head then? e.g. page specific css styles and scripts. Because if I put get_header() into the template that ajax loads, I get a great white page...