# Page template dynamic links based on browser size

Tags: javascript

I have a page template that links though to another php file to define what is displayed. The code for the page is -

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>  

<?php if(!is_front_page()): ?>
  <div id="pageHead" class="withBorder">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php $page_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ttrust_page_description_value", true); ?>
    <?php if ($page_description) : ?>
      <p><?php echo $page_description; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>             
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>         

<div id="content" class="fullProjects clearfix">

  <?php the_content(); ?>               

  <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/projects.php'); ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I would like to add code that changes which linked file it accesses based on the browser size, is this possible?

The line that links is - `<?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/projects.php'); ?>`

Thanks

Jason

Comment: The answer you got to [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/113175/21376) is essentially the answer to this question as well.

Comment: I have tried using that code on the template page but I must be implementing it wrong as I haven't been able to make it work.